# Styling and scripting SVG document referencing different SVG document

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I'm playing around with SVG and HTML5. Currently I'm checking possibilities of client-site SVG generation. The idea is that HTML5 is served with `<embed>` element which contains an XML document describing a hex-based game map (in my own "format"). That document has attached XSLT transform pointing to an XSL file (on server) that makes an SVG out of the document. I wanted to make different hexes of the map in separate SVG files (stored on server) and the generated SVG map would just reference them.

This puts you "in the context". Yet true question starts bellow HTML5 so here we go.

---

How to reference from an SVG document other SVG documents (or their fragments) so that the included content would be available for styling and scripting? It seems that elements `<use>` and `<image>` are quite limited in adding a "cloned fragment" that is not part of the document (even for scripts...). I'm not sure how about `<animation>` from SVG 1.2 but I guess its the same.

I clearly lack a primitive C++ preprocessor-like `#inlcude`.

The standard encourages use of `<defs>` and `<symbol>` for adding meaning and accessibility. Yet it seems that once you do that (and thus have to reference the symbols with `<use>`) you are out of luck with styling. I don't see how to use the same symbol with changed styles.

All this makes reuse and presentation/contents separation much harder.

Are there any ways to avoid those issues?

Answer (score 0):

Since lack of support I continued with experimenting limiting SVG renderers to few popular browsers. Also I checked only styling since I'm not good with JavaScript.

*(My tests were done from a local file which might matter in some cases.)*

---

I checked following browsers: Internet Explorer, Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, Opera and Safari. I keep them all updated (Opera and Safari were just downloaded) so they in their current versions.

As to styling I checked following features:

1. `<image>`,
2. `<use>`,
3. `<animation>` (from SVG 1.2 Tiny, otherwise I used 1.1).

All three had been arranged with CSS style in main file and CSS style in the referenced file. Further the referenced files where provided with CSS style in 3 flavors:

- `xml-stylesheet` processing instruction,
- `<style>` element with `@import` referencing external CSS file (same file as with the processing instruction)
- `<style>` element with the proper contents.

---

With `<image>` no browser took into account style from main document (as expected). Yet all browsers but the IE didn't took into account style of the referenced document if it was placed in external file (and referenced by `xml-stylesheet` or `@import`).

I'm not sure who is doing bad here. Usually you would blame IE in such cases yet IE behavior seems better here so maybe this time its the others that are wrong.

Also Opera was somewhat random. If I kept refreshing the page it sometimes showed as IE would but mostly as other browsers (so lacking style in some cases).

---

With `<use>` (referencing root `<svg>` element in the referenced file) Firefox behaved properly using both referenced file styles (no matter of means in which they were provided) and main file styles.

Opera used referenced file styles (no matter of means in which they were provided) but didn't include main file styles.

Other browsers didn't show the referenced file at all.

---

With `<animation>` only Opera worked. And it did the same as with `<use>`. Others didn't show the referenced file at all.

---

In the end I checked also `<use>` referencing a `<symbol>` inside the file. And all browsers acted properly.

---

This leads to a sad conclusion that SVG files separation and reuse is nearly impossible (at least in Web environment).

Comment: Browsers versions for future reference: (1) IE 9.0 (2) Chrome 22.0 (3) Firefox 15.0 (4) Opera 12.02 (5) Safari 5.1.